# In nested recyclerview, child recyclerview's GridLayoutManager.getChildCount() gives total item count

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I am using a `RecyclerView` inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`.The `RecyclerView` has another 2 `RecyclerView` (for now; it may increase). In my second `RecyclerView` i am trying to implement infinite scrolling. But my `RecyclerView.getItemCount()` and `RecyclerView.getChildCount()` are giving same value. Also the 2nd re has `GridLayoutManager` and `GridlayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` always gives 0 and `GridLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()` always gives list size - 1 in `OnScrolled` of the `RecyclerView`. What is causing this and what should i do to implement the infinite scrolling.

fragment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_standard"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_standard">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

parent_recyclerview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_standard"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_standard"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_standard"
    android:textColor="@color/label_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_standard"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="MOments"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/section_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/events_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

onScrollListener for child recycler view

```
  RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            GridLayoutManager manager = (GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            int itemSize = manager.getItemCount();
            int firstVisibleItem = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int visibleChIldCount = manager.getChildCount();
            Logger.e(TAG,"=============== START =====================");
            Logger.e(TAG, "itemSize: " + itemSize);
            Logger.e(TAG, "firstVisibleitem: " + firstVisibleItem);
            Logger.e(TAG, "visibleChIldCount: " + visibleChIldCount);
            Logger.e(TAG,"mLayoutManager.firstCOmpletely: "+ manager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition());
            Logger.e(TAG,"mLayoutManager. lastcompletey: "+ manager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition());
                Logger.e(TAG,"mLayoutManager.findLastVisible: "+ manager.findLastVisibleItemPosition());
            Logger.e(TAG,"=================END ================");
            if (itemSize >= firstVisibleItem + visibleChIldCount){
                Logger.e("", "loading");
                    mLoadMoreListener.loadMore();

            } else {
                Logger.e(TAG, "not Loading");
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: Did you find the issue and/or solution to this? I am experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: the recycler view was showing all the childs at same time without recycling the views ( not just the child visible in screen)
I then tracked the scrolled amount of the recycler view and compared with the height of the recycler view. let me know if you solved or not otherwise i will give you some code ( when i can probably in couple hours)

Comment: I too am facing this issue. If you can then please do add the code as an answer and accept it. It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. But i will post my solution here if in case someone else is looking for them.

In the adapter of the parent recycler view i have set tag for the view

```
@Override
public SectionRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_section, parent, false);
    view.setTag(viewType);
    return new SectionRowHolder(view);
}
```

The `SectionRowHolder` is simple ViewHolder with a `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` property with getter and setter.

```
public class SectionRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener;

    public SectionRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.section_list);

    }

    public RecyclerView.OnScrollListener getCustomScrollListener() {
        return mOnScrollListener;
    }

    public void setCustomScrollListener(RecyclerView.OnScrollListener mOnScrollListener) {
        this.mOnScrollListener = mOnScrollListener;
    }
}
```

Then in the `onBindViewHolder` for the child with infinite scrolling I have implemented the load more logic in scroll listener and set to the child RecyclerView.

```
 RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        boolean loadEnable = false;

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            mTotalScrolled += dy;
            if ((mTotalScrolled + LOAD_MORE_ENABLE_HEIGHT) > recyclerView.getHeight() && loadEnable) {
                loadEnable = false;
                mLoadMoreListener.loadMore();
            } else {
                loadEnable = true;
            }
        }
    };
    holder.setCustomScrollListener(scrollListener);
    holder.recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

Here `LOAD_MORE_ENABLE_HEIGHT` is offset from bottom of the child recycler view to initialize the `loadmore()` logic and `mLoadMoreListener` is callback to the fragment or activity.

Finally for passing the scoll listener from parent recycler view to the child recycler vew, in my parent `RecyclerView`'s `onScrollListener`

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            View v = mRecyclerView.findViewWithTag(CHILD_RECYCLERVIEW_TAG);
            SectionedLifeAtAdapter.SectionRowHolder viewHolder =
                    (SectionedLifeAtAdapter.SectionRowHolder) mRecyclerView
                            .findContainingViewHolder(v);
            if (viewHolder.getCustomScrollListener() != null)
                viewHolder.getCustomScrollListener().onScrolled((RecyclerView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.section_list), dx, dy);

            Logger.e(TAG, ">>> call to on scrolled listener >>>");
        }
    });
```

Here CHILD_RECYCLERVIEW_TAG is the view type that you set in the `onCreateViewHolder` of the parent Adapter. 
It kind of look like messy but it did the job for me without any issues.